# JQuery Date Time Picker not working with grails 2.3.1

Tags: jquery, grails

I upgraded my go home notes app from 2.3.0 to 2.3.1. Now, my jqueryDatePicker doesn't work. The calendar is not displayed when I click in the date field. I compared the page source for the previous version vs this one. The only difference that I see is that the commas and the quotes are replaced by unicode characters. I have the datePicker on several pages and it fails in every case. So, it isn't like I have a typo in a certain gsp that somehow causes this. The necessary jquery and jquery-ui files are included. Same page worked before.

**Grails 2.3.0:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#reportTargetDate').datepicker({
    dateOnly:true, dateFormat:'mm-dd-yy', timeFormat:'h:mm tt'
});
```

**Grails 2.3.1:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#reportTargetDate').datepicker({
    dateOnly:true\u002c dateFormat:\u0027mm-dd-yy\u0027\u002c timeFormat:\u0027h:mm tt\u0027
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10641 and the linked issues. Can you test with http://hudson.grails.org/job/grails_core_2.3.x/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build/distributions/grails-2.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.zip to see if it fixes your problem?

Comment: I'm having a problem starting this version of grails (see below). I'll go back to 2.3.0 for now, but if you can help me resolve the following issue, I'll be glad to try the 2.3.2 version. Thanks!| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails:grails-bootstrap:jar:2.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails:grails-bootstrap:jar:2.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT